# Use ID instead of IRI in show/edit-URL

Tags: react-admin, api-platform.com, hydra-core

I'm using Symfony with API Platform on a server for my REST API.
The client uses React-admin with the Hydra data provider.

My problem is that the pages for viewing or editing resources have a very ugly URL, because it uses the IRI instead of just the ID.

[image]

Instead of `tags/%2Fapi%2Ftags%2F8/show`, the path should be `tags/8/show`.
How do I accomplish that?

Comment: Did you by any chance find a solution for this issue?

Comment: Nope. I reported this on the GitHub repository and apparently this is intentional. Honestly, this is kind of a deal breaker and makes this package unusable to me.